# Is cm launcher hermful?

Tags: 5.1-lollipop

I have installed cm launcher. Its fine but i am scared if it harm my personal data.i mean is it can find my personal data like photoes, media, phone, message ?

Answer (score 1):

CM Launcher is potentially harmful, it acts  as backdoor for many malwares, adwares, bloatwares.

It installs apps such as battery saver which are installed as system apps, meaning you won't be able to uninstall without rooting your device.  You should not use it or even install it.

Comment: It might be useful to read this latest (2018/11/26) [Android Central](https://www.androidcentral.com/eight-android-apps-2-billion-downloads-are-committing-ad-click-fraud) blog report about "CM Launcher" and its ad-click actions.

Answer (score 0):

It wont harm your files but might repeatedly ask you for installing useless battery saver, file manager etc apps. My experience with CM Launcher was that it worked fine for a few days but then its buggy nature became apparent and I started facing frequent freezes and crashes.

I won't really recommend using launchers however bad your phone's UI is, as it only hampers performance, but still if you need one, Nova Launcher should be a good, stable choice. I have been using it on my old phone for almost 8-9 months without any problems, and it is pretty customizable without purchasing the prime version. I have not faced any problems and it is a solid, stable launcher with no clutter. I have also tried GO Launcher, Next Launcher 3d, and Kitkat/Lollipop launchers but I would prefer Nova launcher anyday.

Comment: It might be useful to read this latest (2018/11/26) [Android Central](https://www.androidcentral.com/eight-android-apps-2-billion-downloads-are-committing-ad-click-fraud) blog report about "CM Launcher" and its ad-click actions.